# Converting a Java EnumSet to an Array

Tags: scala

I'm trying to make a converter:

```
scala>   implicit def enumSetToArray[T : ClassTag](enumSet: EnumSet[T]): Array[T] = enumSet.toArray[T](new Array[T](enumSet.size()))
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[T]
 required: Array[T with Object]
Note: T >: T with Object, but class Array is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ >: T with Object`. (SLS 3.2.10)
         implicit def enumSetToArray[T : ClassTag](enumSet: EnumSet[T]): Array[T] = enumSet.toArray[T](new Array[T](enumSet.size()))
                                                                                                       ^
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[T with Object]
 required: Array[T]
Note: T with Object <: T, but class Array is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: T`. (SLS 3.2.10)
         implicit def enumSetToArray[T : ClassTag](enumSet: EnumSet[T]): Array[T] = enumSet.toArray[T](new Array[T](enumSet.size()))
                                                                                                      ^
```

Ideas? My understanding is that I have to use the ClassTag to save the class from erasure so that reflection can instantiate the array, but apparently doing so messes with the variance.

Comment: I don't know where Object comes from, but I did hit this one: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8360

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
implicit def enumSetToArray[T <: Enum[T]](enumSet: EnumSet[T])(implicit ev: ClassTag[T]): Array[T] = enumSet.toArray[T](new Array[T](enumSet.size))
```